# Hyperledger Fabric Simples issue Run ./byfn.sh -m up failed

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I want to build first-network of Hyperledger Fabric Samples

I get the simple code from git then download the platform-specific binaries follow
 the guide http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/v1.0.5/samples.html
But when I run the command  ./byfn.sh -m generate there are different output in my screen and when I run ./byfn.sh -m up , the error occurred

```
Build your first network (BYFN) end-to-end test

Channel name : mychannel
Creating channel...
CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.key
CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt
CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
CORE_PEER_ID=cli
CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO
CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
+ peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls true --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
+ res=2
+ set +x
2018-04-04 09:59:34.078 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x63 pc=0x7fc6bfc34259]

runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0xf11259, 0x2a)
    /opt/go/src/runtime/panic.go:605 +0x95
runtime.sigpanic()
    /opt/go/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:351 +0x2b8

goroutine 25 [syscall, locked to thread]:
runtime.cgocall(0xbf3800, 0xc420027de8, 0xf0fa21)
    /opt/go/src/runtime/cgocall.go:132 +0xe4 fp=0xc420027da8 sp=0xc420027d68 pc=0x4023b4
net._C2func_getaddrinfo(0x7fc6b00008c0, 0x0, 0xc42038a3c0, 0xc42000e838, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    net/_obj/_cgo_gotypes.go:86 +0x5f fp=0xc420027de8 sp=0xc420027da8 pc=0x5f893f
net.cgoLookupIPCNAME.func2(0x7fc6b00008c0, 0x0, 0xc42038a3c0, 0xc42000e838, 0xc4203822a0, 0x7ffe5b6e1a3a, 0x13)
    /opt/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:151 +0x13f fp=0xc420027e40 sp=0xc420027de8 pc=0x5ffedf
net.cgoLookupIPCNAME(0x7ffe5b6e1a3a, 0x13, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:151 +0x175 fp=0xc420027f38 sp=0xc420027e40 pc=0x5fa195
net.cgoIPLookup(0xc420382360, 0x7ffe5b6e1a3a, 0x13)
    /opt/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:203 +0x4d fp=0xc420027fc8 sp=0xc420027f38 pc=0x5fa8dd
runtime.goexit()
    /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2337 +0x1 fp=0xc420027fd0 sp=0xc420027fc8 pc=0x45e391
created by net.cgoLookupIP
    /opt/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:213 +0xaf

goroutine 1 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.DialContext(0x7fc6bfe577e0, 0xc4203821e0, 0x7ffe5b6e1a3a, 0x18, 0xc420355780, 0x4, 0x4, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/clientconn.go:422 +0x532
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/comm.(*grpcClient).NewConnection(0xc4203705f0, 0x7ffe5b6e1a3a, 0x18, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/comm/client.go:217 +0x389
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/common.(*OrdererClient).Broadcast(0xc42038a270, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc420153b10, 0xbc3839)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/common/ordererclient.go:50 +0x6c
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/common.GetBroadcastClient(0x380, 0xc420184a00, 0x138, 0x138)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/common/broadcastclient.go:41 +0x3e
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel.InitCmdFactory.func1(0xc420335680, 0xc420335e30, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel/channel.go:136 +0x29
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel.sendCreateChainTransaction(0xc420265360, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel/create.go:164 +0xa7
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel.executeCreate(0xc420265360, 0xc420265360, 0x0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel/create.go:178 +0x2f
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel.create(0xc4201f7680, 0xc4201f5860, 0x1, 0xa, 0x0, 0xd5afc0, 0x16705c0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel/create.go:213 +0x40
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel.createCmd.func1(0xc4201f7680, 0xc4201f5860, 0x1, 0xa, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel/create.go:59 +0x52
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute(0xc4201f7680, 0xc4201f5720, 0xa, 0xa, 0xc4201f7680, 0xc4201f5720)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:599 +0x3e8
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC(0x164d4e0, 0x11, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:689 +0x2fe
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute(0x164d4e0, 0x7d, 0xc420014035)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:648 +0x2b
main.main()
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/main.go:112 +0x5e1

goroutine 19 [runnable]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/transport.(*http2Client).keepalive(0xc420332340)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/transport/http2_client.go:1272
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/transport.newHTTP2Client
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/transport/http2_client.go:292 +0xdd2

goroutine 18 [runnable]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/transport.(*http2Client).controller(0xc420332340)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/transport/http2_client.go:1225
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/transport.newHTTP2Client
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/transport/http2_client.go:290 +0xd2e

goroutine 10 [syscall]:
os/signal.signal_recv(0x0)
    /opt/go/src/runtime/sigqueue.go:131 +0xa6
os/signal.loop()
    /opt/go/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:22 +0x22
created by os/signal.init.0
    /opt/go/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:28 +0x41

goroutine 21 [runnable]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/golang.org/x/net/trace.allocFamily(0xc42035a0c0, 0x19, 0x16c6c40)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/golang.org/x/net/trace/trace.go:514
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/golang.org/x/net/trace.New
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/golang.org/x/net/trace/trace.go:359 +0x235

goroutine 16 [runnable]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/transport.(*http2Client).reader(0xc420332340)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/transport/http2_client.go:1137
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/transport.newHTTP2Client
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/transport/http2_client.go:260 +0xbf8

goroutine 20 [runnable]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*addrConn).transportMonitor(0xc420120540)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/clientconn.go:990
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*ClientConn).resetAddrConn
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/clientconn.go:716 +0x67a

goroutine 22 [runnable]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.newClientStream.func3(0x166c200, 0xc420332340, 0xc420120380, 0xc42024d600, 0xc4200ff800)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/stream.go:254
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.newClientStream
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/stream.go:254 +0xe23

goroutine 23 [select]:
net.(*Resolver).LookupIPAddr(0x169d370, 0x1667b40, 0xc4203822a0, 0x7ffe5b6e1a3a, 0x13, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/go/src/net/lookup.go:196 +0x52b
net.(*Resolver).internetAddrList(0x169d370, 0x1667b40, 0xc4203822a0, 0xee7636, 0x3, 0x7ffe5b6e1a3a, 0x18, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /opt/go/src/net/ipsock.go:293 +0x644
net.(*Resolver).resolveAddrList(0x169d370, 0x1667b40, 0xc4203822a0, 0xee7b40, 0x4, 0xee7636, 0x3, 0x7ffe5b6e1a3a, 0x18, 0x0, ...)
    /opt/go/src/net/dial.go:193 +0x594
net.(*Dialer).DialContext(0xc42004f458, 0x1667b40, 0xc4203822a0, 0xee7636, 0x3, 0x7ffe5b6e1a3a, 0x18, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /opt/go/src/net/dial.go:375 +0x248
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.dialContext(0x1667b40, 0xc4203822a0, 0xee7636, 0x3, 0x7ffe5b6e1a3a, 0x18, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc4200ff900, 0xc420284e00)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/go17.go:38 +0xb3
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.DialContext.func1(0x7fc6bfe577e0, 0xc4203822a0, 0x7ffe5b6e1a3a, 0x18, 0x0, 0x0, 0x16571c0, 0xc420140c80)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/clientconn.go:329 +0x86
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.newProxyDialer.func1(0x7fc6bfe577e0, 0xc4203822a0, 0x7ffe5b6e1a3a, 0x18, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc420334e10, 0x0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/proxy.go:121 +0x137
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/transport.dial(0x7fc6bfe577e0, 0xc4203822a0, 0xc42037f790, 0x7ffe5b6e1a3a, 0x18, 0xc42017f780, 0xc4203235c0, 0x7fc6bfe55d10, 0x0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/transport/http2_client.go:119 +0x5a
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/transport.newHTTP2Client(0x7fc6bfe577e0, 0xc4203822a0, 0x7ffe5b6e1a3a, 0x18, 0x0, 0x0, 0xeef4b1, 0xd, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/transport/http2_client.go:157 +0xa7
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/transport.NewClientTransport(0x7fc6bfe577e0, 0xc4203822a0, 0x7ffe5b6e1a3a, 0x18, 0x0, 0x0, 0xeef4b1, 0xd, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/transport/transport.go:505 +0xae
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*addrConn).resetTransport(0xc420120a80, 0xc42038a200, 0xc420120aa0, 0xc42038e108)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/clientconn.go:929 +0x4b4
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*ClientConn).resetAddrConn(0xc4201208c0, 0x7ffe5b6e1a3a, 0x18, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/clientconn.go:702 +0x340
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.DialContext.func3(0xc420382240, 0xc4201208c0, 0x1669a40, 0xc42000e828, 0x7ffe5b6e1a3a, 0x18)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/clientconn.go:417 +0x223
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.DialContext
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/clientconn.go:386 +0x441

goroutine 24 [select]:
net.cgoLookupIP(0x1667b40, 0xc4203822a0, 0x7ffe5b6e1a3a, 0x13, 0xc4201cbc80, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:214 +0x1b0
net.(*Resolver).lookupIP(0x169d370, 0x1667b40, 0xc4203822a0, 0x7ffe5b6e1a3a, 0x13, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/go/src/net/lookup_unix.go:95 +0x12d
net.(*Resolver).(net.lookupIP)-fm(0x1667b40, 0xc4203822a0, 0x7ffe5b6e1a3a, 0x13, 0x3, 0xc420340f00, 0xc420052080, 0x0, 0xc420020000)
    /opt/go/src/net/lookup.go:187 +0x56
net.glob..func10(0x1667b40, 0xc4203822a0, 0xc42037f7f0, 0x7ffe5b6e1a3a, 0x13, 0x42ad09, 0xc400000008, 0xc420052080, 0x0, 0x8db329)
    /opt/go/src/net/hook.go:19 +0x52
net.(*Resolver).LookupIPAddr.func1(0x18, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1)
    /opt/go/src/net/lookup.go:193 +0x5c
internal/singleflight.(*Group).doCall(0x169d360, 0xc420370870, 0x7ffe5b6e1a3a, 0x13, 0xc42038a360)
    /opt/go/src/internal/singleflight/singleflight.go:93 +0x2e
created by internal/singleflight.(*Group).DoChan
    /opt/go/src/internal/singleflight/singleflight.go:86 +0x31f
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Channel creation failed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
========= ERROR !!! FAILED to execute End-2-End Scenario ===========

ERROR !!!! Test failed
```

Please help me to fix this problem thanks!

Comment: What host operating system are you using?  Redhat or Centos by chance?

Comment: Also, you might want to start with v1.1.0 which was recently release: http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/samples.html

Comment: Centos and I try again to start with v1.1.0 but there are same error

Comment: There are also add behaviors sometimes depending on how the resolver on the host is set up.  I added another option above as well to try.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to resolve this by adding `GODEBUG=netdns=go` to the environment variables section of your the Docker Compose file(s).

If you take a look at https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.1/first-network/base/peer-base.yaml, you can modify the contents like this:

```
version: '2'

services:
  peer-base:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - GODEBUG=netdns=go
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
      # bridge network as the peers
      # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_byfn
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO
      #- CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: peer node start
```

The other possible solution is to add the dns_search property:

```
version: '2'

services:
  peer-base:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:$IMAGE_TAG
    dns_search: .
    environment:
      - GODEBUG=netdns=go
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
      # bridge network as the peers
      # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_byfn
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO
      #- CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: peer node start
```

or try both as well

Comment: Thanks for help, and you point out the reason of this error. I open my /etc/resolv.conf file and find `options timeout:2 attempts:3 rotate single-request-reopen` setting. I remove this line and try again successful.

Comment: Thank you ! I have exactly same issue and fixed by the removing "options single-request-reopen" from /etc/resolv.conf. But why this configuration causes SEGV ?? I'm very curious about it.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have mismatched the version of the samples and Hyperledger Fabric images and binaries (I noticed that the version of the output matches code added for v1.1.0). Before running the first-network sample (or any other) make sure that you checkout the corresponding version of the fabric-samples git repository for the docker images and binaries you downloaded.

e.g.

```
git clone https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples.git
git checkout v1.0.6
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/v1.0.6/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s 1.0.6
cd first-network
./byfn.sh -m generate
...
```

Comment: I'm sure the version of  images and code are right,but I'm not sure my go environment is right. My go path set /opt/go, but the log show CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger..

Answer (score 0):

Its an issue of dns-go. Add this tag to the environment of peer container in  docker-compose.yml.

**- GODEBUG=netdns=go**