# Hyperledger Fabric: Peer nodes fail to restart with byfn script when machine is shut down while network is running

Tags: amazon-web-services, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, peer

I have a hyperledger fabric network running on a single AWS instance using the default byfn script.

ERROR: Orderer, cli, CA docker containers show "Up" status. Peers show "Exited" status.

Error occurs when:

1. Byfn network is running, machine is rebooted (not in my control but because of some external reason).
2. Network is left running overnight without shutting the machine. Shows same status next morning.

Error shown:

```
docker ps -a
```

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS                    NAMES
b0523a7b1730        hyperledger/fabric-tools:latest     "/bin/bash"         23 seconds ago      Up 21 seconds                                        cli
bfab227eb4df        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      "peer node start"   28 seconds ago      Exited (2) 23 seconds ago                            peer1.org1.example.com
6fd7e818fab3        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      "peer node start"   28 seconds ago      Exited (2) 19 seconds ago                            peer1.org2.example.com
1287b6d93a23        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      "peer node start"   28 seconds ago      Exited (2) 22 seconds ago                            peer0.org2.example.com
2684fc905258        hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest   "orderer"           28 seconds ago      Up 26 seconds               0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp   orderer.example.com
93d33b51d352        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      "peer node start"   28 seconds ago      Exited (2) 25 seconds ago                            peer0.org1.example.com

Attaching docker log: https://hastebin.com/ahuyihubup.cs

Only the peers fail to start up.
Steps I have tried to solve the issue:

1. docker start $(docker ps -aq) or manually, starting individual peers.
2. byfn down, generate and then up again. Shows the same result as above.
3. Rolled back to previous versions of fabric binaries. Same result on 1.1, 1.2 and 1.4. In older binaries, error is not repeated if network is left running overnight but repeats when machine is restarted.
4. Used older docker images such as 1.1 and 1.2.
5. Tried starting up only one peer, orderer and cli.
6. Changed network name and domain name.
7. Uninstalled docker, docker-compose and reinstalled.
8. Changed port numbers of all nodes.
9. Tried restarting without mounting any volumes.

The only thing that works is reformatting the AWS instance and reinstalling everything from scratch. Also, I am NOT using AWS blockchain template.
Any help would be appreciated. I have been stuck on this issue for a month now.

Comment: Most probably some corrupt file or drivers. I would definitely investigate docker logs of every containers for anomalies? If that isn't satisfactory - I would check system logs. 
In addition to that, I would create a new replica of existing network with exact settings/configuration on different ec2 instance to check whether the issue persist across different servers.

Comment: @NirajKumar Yes the issue persists across different servers. I have attached the docker log in the question. Was that of any help? Which system logs are you referring to?

Comment: I did see the log. I would recommend that - next time when you are building the replica on different server - keep extra memory handy. I am not sure about your EC2 instance configuration, so I am of the opinion that less than required memory might be the issue. And, I would update the configurations (docker compose file & the shell file) to take benefit of docker swarm which restarts a container in the event of failure.

Comment: @NirajKumar Details about Configuration: t3.medium instance, 4 GB/69 GB. On a different server, before and after creating the network, available memory changes from 3.3 GB to 2.9 GB

Comment: @NirajKumar I worked with Docker Swarm for multiple instances and it showed the same error.

Comment: Strange! Docker swarm should restart the peer nodes automatically. That's what it does. Well, I will post more if new information comes up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error resolved by adding following lines to peer-base.yaml:

```
GODEBUG=netdns=go
dns_search: .
```

Thanks to @gari-singh for the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49649678/5248781